# Determining when a sprite passes into another sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two sprites, a small falling object with a dynamic physics body and a bucket with a static physics body. The bucket can be moved by the player's interaction with the game. The goal is to catch the falling object.

How can I detect when the falling object falls into the bucket, not just collides at the edge of the bucket's volume. I ask because I will then be removing the falling item from its parent (the scene) and do not want it to be visible when it is removed, as it should be completely behind the bucket.

I have considered using edges to allow the falling object to bounce off of the sides of the bucket, but am not yet sure how to recognize when the object falls inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your physics body only be the bottom of the bucket for contact,  When your ball hits the bottom, you know he is inside.  If you are worried about having collision on the sides, then add a child node with a second body designed for collision, not contact

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding another small invisible child sprite to the bucket.  make it the size of the bottom of the bucket.  then just detect the falling object's collision with that child sprite instead.